# Using Sysinternals ProcMon improves performance of sluggish application

Tags: wpf, performance, windows-7, sysinternals

Our WPF application works on most user's workstations, but performance is sluggish on one particular user's laptop when the application is responding to some UI work (a Solution Explorer bound to a property grid). I installed Sysinternals Process Explorer, clicked on the process in its Process window, and to my surprise, the sluggishness of the application goes away! Does anyone know what Process Explorer could inadvertently be doing to improve the performance of the application?

Comment: Tell the user to disable or uninstall his anti-malware.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

Scan the machine for malware.
A quick check will be to rename to proexp executable, rerun it and check if the performance still getting better.

There're all kinds of malware out there, some of them are disabling themselfs when detecting anti-malware tools, like sysinternals (procmon & procexp). It may be your case - running procexp made the malware to be disabled and thus increasing performance. read here more: [The Case of the Sysinternals-Blocking Malware](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2011/03/08/3392087.aspx)